# F# Async.FromBeginEnd calling End function when it shouldn't?

Tags: asynchronous, f#, io

I am doing some low level socket work using F# and am making everything asynchronous.  I have a socket that I am using to listen for connections using an async workflow to handle them so it is using this to wrap the Socket.BeginListen() and Socket.EndListen().

```
member socket.AsyncAccept () =
    Async.FromBeginEnd( socket.BeginAccept, endOrDisposed socket.EndAccept null )
```

When I want to stop listening, at the moment I am doing a Socket.Close() on it which will cause the async operation started by Socket.BeginAccept() to complete.

Originally I then ran into a problem as the FromBeginEnd() function would always call the EndXXX() function no matter how the operation started by BeginXXX() completed.  In some cases this would lead to an ObjectDisposed exception by the EndXXX() function as by the time it was called the Socket had been closed and disposed.  I added a little handler function which would filter those exceptions out thus:

```
let endOrDisposed endFunc defaultResult iar = try endFunc iar with | _ -> defaultResult
```

This does the trick, but not when running in debug.  I am well aware that the Just My Code option can be used to hide the exception but this could be happening with some other IO operations on a more frequent basis so I also would rather not have processor time wasted on raising and catching exceptions which shouldn't really be there in the first place.  Also I might not want to hide where other exceptions are being thrown as they could by in areas where I do need to debug.

I've looked at the code for Async.FromBeginEnd and it is wired to always call the EndXXX() function no matter what, I'm not sure this is the best behaviour, perhaps I should write a replacement for it?  Or does anyone have any other ideas for elegant solutions?

---

I just found (sure I'd looked before though) this in the docs:

> To cancel a pending call to the BeginAccept() method, close the
>   Socket. When the Close() method is called while an asynchronous
>   operation is in progress, the callback provided to the BeginAccept()
>   method is called. A subsequent call to the EndAccept() method will
>   throw an ObjectDisposedException to indicate that the operation has
>   been cancelled.

I still don't like the exception, even if it is by design.  I'd prefer to find a way to not call EndXXX() on a disposed object.  Perhaps I can mix some CancellationToken magic into this somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I would make use of the optional `cancelAction` argument to `Async.FromBeginEnd` here:

```
type Socket with
  member this.AsyncAccept () =
    let canceled = ref false
    let endAccept iar = if not !canceled then this.EndAccept iar else null
    let cancel () = canceled := true; this.Close ()
    Async.FromBeginEnd (this.BeginAccept, endAccept, cancelAction = cancel)
```

This way you can use `Async`'s builtin cancellation functionality (which is of course based on `CancellationToken`) without touching a `CancellationToken` directly. (I.e., you should **not** be calling `Socket.Close` for cancellation purposes.)

Answer (score 0):

What's needed is a method to interrupt the Async.FromBeginEnd process and stop it trying to EndAccept in the case where the socket is being closed (this probably extends to other operations besides Accept).

Instead of having calls to Socket.Close() I used a CancellationTokenSource and registered a handler with it which will call Socket.Close():

```
cts.Token.Register (fun () -> listener.Close()) |> ignore
```

and then instead of passing Async.FromBeginEnd the EndAccept function directly it now goes via a function that will stop the EndAccept being called if the token has been cancelled.

```
let endOrDisposed endFunc defaultResult iar = try endFunc iar with | _ -> defaultResult
let endIfNotCancelled endFunc defaultResult (token:CancellationToken) iar = if token.IsCancellationRequested then defaultResult else endOrDisposed endFunc defaultResult iar

type Socket with
  member socket.AsyncAccept (cancelToken) =
    Async.FromBeginEnd( socket.BeginAccept, endIfNotCancelled socket.EndAccept null cancelToken)
```

This still uses my function to filter out and ignore exceptions (I don't think exceptions are very exceptional when it comes to networking, and in this apps case there is nothing it would do in response anyway).